# Native Ads star rating coming back as 0.0?

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, native-ads

I have implemented [Native Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/advanced) in my app. Everything works fine, except for one problem:

If the app has a star rating, it always returns `0.0`.

Here's my code:

```
private fun loadAd() {
    val builder = AdLoader.Builder(context, getString(R.string.test_admob_app_unit_id))
    /** Build ad */
    builder
        .forUnifiedNativeAd { unifiedNativeAd ->
            /** Populate UnifiedNativeAdView with loaded NativeAd */
            if (activity == null) return@forUnifiedNativeAd
            val unifiedNativeAdView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_unified, null) as UnifiedNativeAdView
            populateUnifiedNativeAdView(unifiedNativeAd, unifiedNativeAdView)


private fun populateUnifiedNativeAdView(nativeAd: UnifiedNativeAd, adView: UnifiedNativeAdView) {
    currentNativeAd?.destroy()
    currentNativeAd = nativeAd
    /** Set the media view */
    adView.mediaView = adView.findViewById<MediaView>(R.id.ad_media)
    adView.mediaView.setImageScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START)
    adView.mediaView.setMediaContent(nativeAd.mediaContent)
    adView.headlineView = adView.findViewById(R.id.headlineText)
    adView.bodyView = adView.findViewById(R.id.bodyText)
    adView.callToActionView = adView.findViewById(R.id.meet)
    adView.iconView = adView.findViewById(R.id.adIcon)
    /** Rating */
    val starRatingView = adView.findViewById<RatingBar>(R.id.rating)
    log("starRating: ${nativeAd.starRating}") // prints 0.0
    log("store: ${nativeAd.store}") // prints Google Play
    nativeAd.starRating.let {
        /** If rating is not null and greater than 0, show rating */
        if (it != null && it > 0.0) starRatingView.rating = it.toFloat() else starRatingView.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    (adView.headlineView as TextView).text = nativeAd.headline
   ...
```

If the ad is not an app, the rating will be null. If it is an app, the rating will be 0.0.

These are test ads, does that affect the rating?